# Jw player installing youtube embed link

Tags: javascript, html, youtube, jwplayer

### Embed link

Is it possible give the youtube embed url to my jw player. I had design of jw player frame which is given by design and in that player I want to use youtube link not crushing any details of design. Not criticize so hard really I search but cannot found any good examples for that.

```
<div class="video-slider-inline">

    <div class="otplayer-wrapper">
        <a href="index-2.html" class="video-overlay-logo"><img src="<? bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/overlay-logo.png" width="123" height="28" alt="" /></a>
        <video class="otplayer" preload="auto" poster="<? bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/video/video-screen.png">
       <source src="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=on22iUlIiww" type="video/mp4">
      <div id="videofallback">Loading the player...</div>
        </video>

    <div class="otplayer-controls">
        <div class="ot-inline-playpause"><i class="fa fa-play"></i><i class="fa fa-pause"></i></div>
        <div class="ot-inline-slider"><div></div></div>
        <div class="ot-inline-time">00:00</div>
        <div class="ot-inline-volume-controls">
        <div class="ot-inline-volume">
        <i class="fa fa-volume-up"></i>
        <i class="fa fa-volume-off"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="ot-inline-volume-slider"><div></div></div>
    </div>
    <div class="ot-inline-fullscreen"><i class="fa fa-desktop"></i></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<? bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/jscript/jwplayer.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<? bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/jscript/jwplayer.html5.js"></script>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Disclaimer** - before I list my answer you should know that playback of YouTube sources in the JW Player is [deprecated](https://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/articles/1406725-youtube-video-embed).  However, it is still included in the player for the time-being.

That being said, using the file option you can embed it like so (taken from the YouTube embed example by JW Player itself):

```
<div id="myElement">Loading the player...</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var playerInstance = jwplayer("myElement");
    playerInstance.setup({
       file: "//www.youtube.com/watch?v=8CjdLYBDUqw",
       width: 640,
       height: 360
    });
</script>
```

The url has to follow one of the following formats:

- //www.youtube.com/watch?v=ylLzyHk54Z0
- //www.youtube.com/v/ylLzyHk54Z0
- //youtu.be/ylLzyHk54Z0

There are a few restrictions on design/UI options since the video is hosted by YouTube:

- YouTube watermark cannot be removed
- Sideloaded or Youtube captions cannot be used
- YouTube advertisements inside of videos cannot be removed
- JW Player's advertising plugins cannot be used.
- Skins will not appear initially on mobile.
- YouTube playlists and/or RSS feeds are unsupported
- HTML5 is the only supported method of playback
- Mobile devices require user interactions to start video playback. This means 
  that playlists do not work seamlessly on mobile.

From my experience with JW Player, the real benefits you get from using it are when you self-host your own videos and can skin/design your own player.  Embedding YouTube videos can be done but you aren't really reaping the benefits of the library (which is why I imagine they are dropping support for this).

In any case, the full guide to embedding YouTube videos with JW PLayer can be found [here](https://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/articles/1406725-youtube-video-embed).